# Terminal wealth distribution from dollar cost averaging

Tags: distribution

If monthly stock market returns follow an IID lognormal distribution, the terminal wealth distribution of investing a lump sum for many years is also lognormal. What is the terminal wealth distribution of monthly investments that grow x% a year, reflecting the experience of someone who invests a fraction of each paycheck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand that you assume multiplicative gross returns, $W_t=W_{t-1}R_{t-1,t}=W_{t-2}R_{t-1,t}R_{t-2,t-1}$ and so on.

Let's assume that you are investing $I$ at the onset, and increase your investment by a factor of $1+\alpha$ each period, then your (random) final wealth will be:

$$
\begin{align}
W_N&=I\left[\prod_{i=1}^NR_i+(1+\alpha)\prod_{i=2}^NR_i+\ldots+(1+\alpha)^{N-2}R_{N-1}R_{N}+(1+\alpha)^{N-1}R_N\right]\\
&=I\sum_{j=1}^
{N}(1+\alpha)^{j-1}\prod_{i=j}^NR_i
\end{align}
$$

As the lognormal distribution [does not have a well defined characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Characteristic_function_and_moment_generating_function), there exists no sensible closed form / simple numerical-integral-like representation for the distribution. You can, of course, compute the first couple of moments of $W_N$ and try your luck with a [Cornish-Fisher expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornish%E2%80%93Fisher_expansion) around the lognormal distribution, or something the like.